# Read/Write Permissions in Mac OS Catalina

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, macos-catalina

I'm just merely trying to change my system icons (namely messages and mail) but don't have the necessary read/write access and when I try to change that, it says just that, that I don't have the necessary permissions. I don't want to csrutil disable the whole system from the recovery disk so if anyone has any idea how to do that, yayyyy. I would be appreciative.

Thank you!